# How to retrieve data from a dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I am trying to extract data from a data frame base on condition.

[image: Dataframe I have]

I need to get only values having only fans or the Top 0.10% in the data frame. I am able to get the value using the if condition:-

```
for i in range(len(dataframe['Display_Name'])):
    if "onlyfans" in dataframe['Description'][i] or "OnlyFans" in dataframe['Display_Name'][i] or "TOP 0.01%" in dataframe['Display_Name'][i] or "top 0.01%" in dataframe['Content'][i]:
        print(dataframe['Display_Name'][i])
        print(dataframe['Description'][i])
        print(dataframe['ID'][i])
        print(i)
        print("*"*25)
```

but I am getting output like this:-

```
Shelly d'Inferno @ OnlyFans
Swedish muse/showgirl/ape. #HODLing on for dear life! #GME #AMC to the moon!  
112204991
9
*************************
PSG Kagura
ICI C'EST PARIS  (j'habite dans le sud)  | 2nd @2onlyfansKagura
1340765931887321088
47
*************************
Jack $300 OnlyFans
Data Analyst |
if you ask for context, you're part of the problem |
you don't know who I am |
None of these opinions are my own.
2369480532
52
*************************
OnlyFans
lonely
958973284053286918
55
*************************
cileksu $free onlyfans
24 ücretsiz onlyfans hesabım için linke tıkla⬇️ VIP hesabım için @cileksu8 
1558401021671620608
176
*************************
cileksu $free onlyfans
24 ücretsiz onlyfans hesabım için linke tıkla⬇️ VIP hesabım için @cileksu8 
1558401021671620608
180
*************************
SmashBros OnlyFans
‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️
1422616372408897542
290
*************************
```

I want a new data frame that I can save into a csv or excel file meeting the above conditions.

Comment: Please read the w3school. This is the basic knowledge of pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
filtering = ((dataframe['Description'].str.contains("onlyfans")) | (dataframe['Display_Name'].str.contains("OnlyFans")) | (dataframe['Display_Name'].str.contains("TOP 0.01%")) | (dataframe['Content'].str.contains("top 0.01%")))

dataframe[filtering]
```

Pandas "or"-[operator](https://www.statology.org/or-operator-in-pandas/)

Comment: Thanks! When I use this statement it's giving me KeyError: False. However, when I am using my condition which I stated above giving me the correct result.

Also, tried :-
("onlyfans" in dataframe['Description']) | ("OnlyFans" in dataframe['Display_Name']) | ("TOP 0.01%" in dataframe['Display_Name']) | ("top 0.01%" in dataframe['Content'])  which is giving result as False.

Comment: Edited, try again.